# Where to find the latest Kubuntu (13.04) with autoinstaller?

Tags: installation, kubuntu

I've just now learnt that Kubuntu 13.04 doesn't provide auto installer for dual boot system. Ubuntu provides. Lubuntu provides, Xubuntu provides. Kubuntu force you to install manually. Do partition, install and set GRUB, etc. So painful surprise. Only two alternatives, either it takes 100% of disk or do it yourself.

I downloaded the `.iso` file from their site. So, that version is a "do-it-yourself" version. Where may I find a version with auto installer, as in Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu?

Comment: Are you asking about wubi ? wubi was dropped with 13.04 - see http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/ . There are patches available, but I have not tried them, so can not advise you. If you are familiar with Ubuntu , the graphical installer should not be that difficult, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall and ask if you need help at any specific step.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, No, I'm not talking about Wubi. I'm talking about pure dual-boot with GRUB. In the second link that you provide it is an "Installation type" step (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#Installation_type). So Kubuntu doesn't have it. There is no option `Install Kubuntu alongside existing OSes`. There are only two options: `Erase and install` and `Manual`. And in the `Manual` they offer you to partition you free space for boot sector, swap sector, etc.

Comment: OIC. Well, for what it is worth, personally I ALWAYS do the partitioning prior to running the installer, and use the manual option. IMO windows does best if you defragment and resize with the windows tools first and I find gparted easier to use then the installer partitioning tool. You might want to file a bug report, although it may be viewed as a feature request -

Comment: @Green, sorry to question you but are you sure? I have the impression that the installer shows context-specific screens based on its analysis of the system. So, different systems may see different options.

Comment: I'd look at the existing partition layout before saying Kubuntu has an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although I always do "something else", I'm 100% positive kubuntu will install along with anything. Are you trying to install with the regular desktop version?

Comment: Yes, I think with the regular desktop version. There is only two options to download on Kubuntu site: the latest release and the Long Term Support release. I took the latest release. I'm not afraid to manually partition my disk. But the reason I have chosen Ubuntu and not some other Linux distro is because Ubuntu offers out-of-the-box installation. If Ubuntu doesn't provide it, then I see no no reason to choose Ubuntu. I would better try Debian or Arch. The same work to do.